# can't get node ftp working?

Tags: node.js, express, ftp

super simple question,

I'm using: https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp
And, I have the following in my node app:

```
var Ftp = require("ftp");
var client = new Ftp(); 
client.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("READY!");
  client.list(function(err, list) {
    console.log(list);
    client.end();
  });
});

console.log("connecting...");
client.connect({
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3500
});
console.log("connected.");
console.log(Object.keys(client._events));
```

The output when I run is:

```
connecting...
connected.
[ 'ready' ]
```

The client is NOT responding after it has connected. I've googled around without any progress.The port number 3500 is also the port that my express app runs on. Any other port number gives me a ECONNREFUSED error. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have an FTP server running on `localhost`?

Comment: Are you sure the other defaults are correct for your server setup (e.g. username, password, non-FTPS connection)? If so, you may try setting `debug: console.log` in your connection config to show exactly what's happening behind the scenes.